# Equational identities of $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot, \sin)$

Tags: trigonometry, universal-algebra

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,\sin)$, where $+$ denotes addition, $\cdot$ denotes multiplication, and $\sin$ denotes the sine function. I conjecture that the equational identities of that structure are generated by the associative and commutative laws of addition and multiplication and the distributive law. Is this conjecture true? In other words, what I am really asking is, does the sine function interact non-trivially with addition and multiplication?

Edit: Also, is there an explicit finite basis for the identities of this structure?

Comment: Note that if we add subtraction to our language we do get new identities - for example, since $$\cos(x+x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$ and $\cos^2(y)+\sin^2(y)=1$ we get $$\sin^2(2x)+(1-2\sin^2(x))^2=1$$ which in turn yields for example $$[\sin^2(2x)+(1-2\sin^2(x))^2]x=x.$$

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Can't you turn that into an identity without subtraction by just bringing the subtracted terms to the other side of the equation?

Comment: Or from $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$ and squaring, $\sin^22x=4\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)$. Comes down to the same identity as @Noah found, maybe looks a little nicer.

Comment: @EricWofsey ... yes, yes you can. Derp. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning my and Eric's comments above into an answer, combining the formulas $$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$ and (for example) $$x[\cos^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x)]=x$$ we get $$x[(1-2\sin^2(x))^2+\sin^2(2x)]=x.$$ Expanding out and moving the negative term to the other side yields $$4x\sin^4(x)+x\sin^2(2x)=4x\sin^2(x),$$ which is a nontrivial identity in addition, multiplication, and sine.

I do suspect that there are no nontrivial identities using just addition and sine or just multiplication and sine, however, but I don't immediately see a proof of this. (I've [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164632/does-sine-equationally-interact-with-addition-or-with-multiplication) a separate question about this.)

Comment: Well, then, what is an explicit finite basis for the identities of my structure? Maybe we just have to add your identity, and then we will be done.

Comment: @user107952 I'm personally skeptical that there is a finite basis for the identities, to be honest.

Comment: @user107952 You might ask whether there is a finite basis for identities as a separate question, it's not obvious to me (although again I suspect there isn't).